# HTML To PDF Converter dompdf

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, dompdf

I want to use dompdf i've downloaded from github and extracted on my webserver but i face error as, (i'm on windows).I also tried this but didn't help

```
      define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);

     <br />
     <b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'DOMPDF' not found in           

     <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental\controller\register.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
```

here's my code

```
    if(!empty($_POST['pr_data'])){
$pr_dt=$_POST['pr_data'];
require_once("../assets/converter/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($pr_dt);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
echo $dompdf;
exit;
}


   jQuery('.btn-print').click(function() {
   var pr_data = jQuery('.tc').html();
   jQuery.post('../controller/register.php', {
     'pr_data': pr_data
   }, function(result) {
   console.log(result);
  });
  });
```

I downloaded dompdf from [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) i didn't use composer for installing i've used third one Download and extract

**UPDATE**
I've also tried checking whether dompdf file path is correct

```
   if(!@include("../assets/converter/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php")) throw new Exception("Failed to include 'script.php'");
```

and check whether class exist

```
if (class_exists('dompdf'))
     { 
        echo "class exist";
     }
     else{
        echo "does not exist";
     }

 if (is_file("../assets/converter/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php"))
    {
        echo "PATH is CORRECT";
        require_once("../assets/converter/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    }
```

now the output

```
      does not exist PATH is CORRECT
      Fatal error: Class 'DOMPDF' not found in            
       C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental\view\createMRA.php on line 83
```

**Update**

I'm able to download a corrupt pdf why so?

```
        Fatal error: Class 'Font' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rental\assets\converter\dompdf\include\font_metrics.cls.php on line 346
```

Comment: Have you validated that the require path is correct for that script you're running?

Comment: yes its correct i've rechecked in browser i can see example and demo when i got dompdf path

Comment: One more thing while including files from path. Define these paths in config file as constants and use constants to include file.

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't updated my question i'm able to download pdf but it is corrupted i think my external css and bootstrap are not getting appied

Comment: Make sure you download the full release archive (e.g. [dompdf_0.6.1.zip](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/download/v0.6.1/dompdf-0.6.1.zip)) instead of just the source. Otherwise you'll be missing some files.

Answer (score 0):

Try including this file ***DOMPDF_INC_DIR/dompdf.cls.php*** to your working file. This is where the DOMPDF class is defined.

Hope this would resolve your issue.

-Naim

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't updated my question i'm able to download pdf but it is corrupted i think my external css and bootstrap are not getting appied

Comment: i really can't add all lines because so body limit is of 30000 char and my char goes about 90100